# Require.js errors after database restore

Tags: requirejs, magento2.2.6

On Magento 2.2.6 I restored from an earlier database. After doing that I flushed the cache, reindexed the site,and deployed static content. I now get require.js errors on every page. On my category page-

```
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding 
"visible: function(){return isVisible() }"
Message: Cannot read property 'hasMessages' of undefined
at UiClass.isVisible (messages.js:51)
at visible (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:67)
at update (knockout.js:4558)
at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
at knockout.js:3002
at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
```

On a different category page-

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){return t(e)}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
at makeError (require.js:166)
at intakeDefines (require.js:1221)
at require.js:1408
```

The Mismatched anonymous define is also on the item page. I didn't change any code so I am not sure what to here. How can I clear these errors?

Answer (score 1):

- Delete all files and folder in

  - `magento2-root/pub/static/*`
  - `magento2-root/var/cache/*`
  - `magento2-root/var/page_cache/*`
  - `magento2-root/var/view_preprocessed/*`
- Redeploy Magento `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- Set proper permissions i.e 777 to all above directories.